# Create trigger prevent insert or update if in the column repeats the values

Tags: mysql, sql, database-trigger

I am new to writing triggers can help me i only have pseudocode and task.

Task:

In table `speaker_t` have two columns:

- `speaker_group_id`
- `language_id`

I want the trigger to prohibit the addition of data if there is an identical language_id in the `specker_group_id` and so that it checks each `specker_group_id`.

should be like this:

speaker_group_id=1->language_id=1,2,3(with no duplicates in language_id in each speaker_group_id
My pseudocode:

```
Create trigger trigger 

on speaker_t

after insert update as

begin
if exists(select speaker_group_id from speaker_t where language_id=1)

begin 

rollback transaction
raiserror("speaker_group_id have this id");
return
end
```

I think that i must write three triggers on each language_id

Comment: Why don't you use constraint on the table to avoid duplicates, one can do that by creating ```CREATE UNIQUE INDEX uq_yourtablename
  ON dbo.yourtablename(column1, column2);```

Comment: I am not clear how your data is organised do you have on row per speaker and language with languages stored as csv values or do you have one row per speaker per language (in your example 3 rows)?

Comment: 'I think that i must write three triggers on each language_id' - definitely not.

Comment: I agree with @Rohit, no need for triggers here, just use a unique index.

Comment: I understand this i did this thank You @Rohit but I thought that i can do only one index be unique in all rows